# how to avoid duplicate values from concatenated datas from table using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, web-services

i am doing auto completion using jquery and web service. Web service is done using linq queries.I concatenated tables from entity model using linq. Now it showing duplicates data.
Help me to avoid duplicate data using linq.

### This is my web service :

```
 public class SearchService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
  [WebMethod]
        public string[] SearchCategory(string searchtxt)
        {
CustSite_INDIAEntities ctx = new CustSite_INDIAEntities();
            var cat1 = from b in ctx.tbl_CategoryLevel1 where b.Cat1_Name.StartsWith(searchtxt) select b.Cat1_Name;
            var cat2 = from b in ctx.tbl_CategoryLevel2 where b.Cat2_Name.StartsWith(searchtxt) select b.Cat2_Name;
            var cat3 = from b in ctx.tbl_CategoryLevel3 where b.Cat3_Name.StartsWith(searchtxt) select b.Cat3_Name;
            var cat4 = from b in ctx.tbl_CategoryLevel4 where b.Cat4_Name.StartsWith(searchtxt) select b.Cat4_Name;
            var cat5 = from b in ctx.tbl_CategoryLevel5 where b.Cat5_Name.StartsWith(searchtxt) select b.Cat5_Name;
            string[] cat10 = cat1.Concat(cat2).Concat(cat3).Concat(cat4).Concat(cat5).ToArray();
 return cat10;
 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `Union` will remove duplicates, while Concat keeps them.